# It gives error as List iterator not decrementable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, stl, iterator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEGXh.png)Below code results in a compilation error, as `std::list`'s iterator is not decrementable:

```
std::list<CItem*>::iterator iter1, iter2;
  std::list<CItem*> listc, list3;
  std::vector<CItem*>::iterator iter;

for(iter1 = listc.begin(); iter1 != listc.end(); iter1++)
  {
    for(iter2 = list3.begin(); iter2 != list3.end(); iter2++)
    {
      if((*iter1)->getID() == (*iter2)->getID())
      {
        iter1 = listc.erase(iter1);
        iter1--;               //this line gives error as list iterator not decrementable
        list3.erase(iter2);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you can, use `std::vector` instead of `std::list`. Or do you *have* to use a list? because it's not recommended to use it for much (except if you need to insert all the time). An alternative would be to keep a "prev" iterator around

Comment: If you ask questions about build errors, please always include the actual errors. Copy-paste them in full and complete, and as text, into your question.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: yes I need to use  std::list

Comment: And what problem is this code supposed to solve? Why do you need to decrement the iterator?

Comment: `std::list` has stable iterators (and thats about the only advantage over `std::vector` I am aware of), so you can remember an iterator from the previous iteration. Though you should explain what the code is supposed to do. Broken code is suboptimal in demonstrating what it should do

Comment: Need to decrement iterator because which is used into the for loop as well

Comment: Actually it gives runtime error not compilation error

Comment: What happens with `iter1--` if `listc.erase(iter1)` returns the `lists.begin()` iterator?

Comment: I assume you want to "offset" the `iter1++` you do in the `for` statement? How about an alternative solution: *Don't* do `iter1++` inside the `for` itself. Instead only do `iter1++` if you don't call `erase`. Then you don't have to do `iter1--`. I.e. `if (...) { /* Doing the erase */ } else { iter1++;  }`

Comment: yes correct listc.erase(iter1) returns the lists.begin() iterator

Comment: @Some programmer dude --but there are two loops, then how to handle for first for loop?

Comment: Only one loop iterates using `iter1`.

Comment: You don't have a compilation error. You have a runtime error.

Comment: "yes correct listc.erase(iter1) returns the lists.begin() iterator" Ok great, now how do you propose to decrement it?